# "Import Files into iTunes" automator action not working

Tags: macos, itunes, automator, osx-yosemite

I'm having an issue with a simple automator action, "Import Files into iTunes". It's the only thing I have in the workflow but when I drop audio files onto the application, the action encounters an error. In trying to figure out what was amiss, I read that there was a version number conflict after iTunes 10, so I followed the instructions [here](http://www.cnet.com/news/itunes-automator-workflows-no-longer-working-after-itunes-10/) but they did not fix the issue. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to try or how to diagnose the issue? I'm running Yosemite (10.10.2) and iTunes 12.1.0.50. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I use an Automator Script for importing my own Library Structure and Sync it with itunes. What iTunes needs are URL-Encoded Strings given to the Workflow element you are looking at. Maybe you can look into that ? I can also share my script if that is of any use to you.